# No fetch option for CordovaCLI 8.0.0

Tags: cordova, npm, cordova-plugins, npm-install, cordova-cli

I can not find any document for Cordova CLI 8.0.0 that support `--nofetch` option.

[Here](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-cli/index.html#cordova-platform-command) is the link to cordova's docs page mentioning the `--nofetch` option in CordovaCLI 7.0.0.

Every time I run `cordova platform command` with 8.0.0 changes node_modules folder. 
Missing some node modules makes my build command failed.

Anyone know this option?

[8.0.0](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova) 's status on npm.js is **BUILD FAILING** but it was released. Should I use it?

Answer (score 3):

As outlined in the [`cordova@8` release announcement](http://cordova.apache.org/news/2017/12/18/tools-release.html), support for `--nofetch` was removed in `cordova@8` under [CB-13055](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-13055).

So as of `cordova@8` all plugins are installed using `npm`.

Moving forward (`cordova@9`?), it's likely the duplication of plugins between `plugins/` and `node_modules/` will be removed and installed plugins will solely exist in `node_modules/`

Comment: Since all plugins are installed using `npm` then it changes my `node_modules` folder. Somehow it makes my `run build command` failed. Any way to fix this issue?

Comment: So how are we supposed to install custom plugins straight from a github URL?

Comment: @DimitriosMatanis `cordova plugin add https://github.com/someone/cordova-plugin-something`

Comment: I have tried that but unfortunately it times out and gives me Failed to fetch plugin h t t p s : //github.com/dimitriscsd/anyline-ocr-cordova-module via registry.
Probably this is either a connection problem, or plugin spec is incorrect.
Check your connection and plugin name/version/URL. There seems to be a bug or something when trying to install plugins from github repos that don't exist in the npm registry

Comment: If you try another plugin e.g. `cordova plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-dialogs` it will work. `https://github.com/dimitriscsd/anyline-ocr-cordova-module` is not working because it's not a valid Cordova plugin repo. The root of the repo must contain `plugin.xml`, etc. (what your `plugin` directory contains).

Comment: Thanks. It's not my plugin. It's Anyline's. I just forked it to fix something with a pull request. I see what you're saying with plugin.xml - I think I read somewhere that there's a parameter to specify where that xml is. I'll give it a shot. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: Unfortunately I tried cordova plugin add https://github.com/dimitriscsd/anyline-ocr-cordova-module.git#:/plugin but it still hangs forever... According to some tutorials I found, that's how you specify where the plugin.xml is. I have a feeling this functionality was dropped...

Comment: I have also made a branch on my repo called "clean" where the plugin files are the in the root directory. This seems to indeed work so you were right.